# Tooltip Title attribute does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, svg, tooltip

When I add this code, tooltip does not appear on SVG Elements (Circle, rect)

I am using this code because I wanto to use `<p>` and `<span>` tag within the tooltip

Code;

```
$(function () {
      $.widget("ui.tooltip", $.ui.tooltip, {
          options: {
              content: function () {
                  return $(this).prop('title');
              }
          }
      });

      $(document).tooltip();
  });
```

It works except svg
When I remove this, it works for svg elements but not `<p>` `<span>` tags

Thanks in advance.

I'm using jquery-ui

Comment: What are you expecting `this` to refer to, because given your code it will be the `window`

Comment: SVG elements have title child elements, html elements have title attributes. I assume the tooltip only supports html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Robert Longson declared in the comment

I assign a title attribute to both elements and children, then it works.

It was like;

```
$( "#elementId" )[ 0 ].title = '<span class="red-span"> TRY OUT </span>';
$( "#elementId" )[ 0 ].children.title = '<span class="red-span"> TRY OUT </span>';
```